# Use LINQ to refactor a WPF, grid.Children iterating method

Tags: linq

My aim is to convert this foreach logic to a single LINQ query.

```
foreach (var anyItem in gridReference.Children)
{
    var enumerableCheck = anyItem as ListBox; 

    if (enumerableCheck != null)
    {
        foreach (var collectionItem in enumerableCheck.Items)
        {
            //check collectionItem is of type T
        }
    } 

    else
    {                    
        //check anyItem is of type T
    }
}
```

I tried my hand at learning linq with this refactoring but the syntax errors are real off putting since im so used to C#. Also I do not know how to assign a working variable in linq which leads to constant casting.

*Attempt:*

```
IEnumerable <T> genericQuery = from UIElement element1 in gridReference.Children
                               where (element1 as ListBox) != null
                               from item in (element1 as ListBox).Items
                               where (item as T) != null
                               select (item as T)

                               from UIElement element2 in gridReference.Children
                               where element2 as T != null
                               select element2;
```

Comment: Purely for the sake of alternatives: `var genericQuery = (from UIElement e in gridReference.Children
        from le in (e as ListBox)?.Items ?? new[]{e}.AsEnumerable()        
        select le).OfType<T>();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested a working query thanks to madOX's encouraging reply.

```
IEnumerable <T> genericQuery = (from element1 in gridReference.Children.OfType <ListBox>()
                                from boxItem in element1.Items.OfType <T>()
                                select boxItem)

                                .Concat (from element2 in gridReference.Children.OfType <T>()
                                select element2);
```

Answer (score 2):

I think it's perfect example to use `let` clause in linq, to check that casting.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383976.aspx

To make sure that you are returning only items that fits to T, you can use `OfType<T>`

```
List<T> result = (from element1 in gridReference.Children
                        let el1ListBox = element1 as ListBox
                        where el1ListBox != null 
                        select el1ListBox.Items.OfType<T>()).ToList();
```

---

EDIT:

According to comment:

```
List<T> result = (from element1 in gridReference.Children.OfType<ListBox>().ToList()
                        select element1.Items.OfType<T>()).ToList();
```

Comment: `gridReference.Children.OfType<ListBox>()`

Comment: I mean: you can use `OfType` twice.

Comment: that edit produces compile error: `Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<T>' WAV2ByteArray`.


Your reply was very encouraging though and motivated me to learn `let`, `OfType<>()`, nested `from` which all helped me to finish a working query!